# Why does calling a property on a string not give an error?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript why does the second line below return `undefined` and not an error?

```
var apple = 'apple';
apple.colour; //undefined
```

Comment: Everything in JS is `object` and can has custom fields

Comment: @MysterX no, that is not true, Strings, numbers, and booleans are *not* objects.

Comment: @Pointy But they're coerced into being objects in cases like this.

Comment: @Pointy string internally creates object.

Comment: Yes, they're coerced to an object instance, but a string is not an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression that evaluates to a primitive value that appears on the left side of a `.` or `[]` operator will be automatically "wrapped" in an object of the appropriate type (String, Number, Boolean).

Thus

```
"hello".length
```

is evaluated as if it were

```
new String("hello").length
```

Comment: In Java, for example, this behavior is called auto-boxing.

Comment: One perfect example would be to try to access an index of a String. Trying to access `apple[0]` would automatically convert the String to an array of character, showing the 'Object wrapping' thing ... Right ?

Comment: @YassineBadache Exactly. Although it won't actually be an array. It's just an object with numeric keys.

Comment: I think this answer still fails to address the question of why it didn't produce an error. Put simply, it's to allow you to set that value to something that *isn't* undefined.